# Extjs focused cell moving with scroll

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using extjs grid Panel with extjs plugin CellEditing, its working fine now I am facing an issue if grid cell is focused and user tried to use any scrollbar with in page, focused cell remain fixed and other grid moving with scroll, as stop scrolling fixed cell moved to its original position inside grid. Need help in this regard.

**Screenshot:**
**[image: Code:]**

**Code:**

```
Ext.define('XPL.view.AccountGridCtr', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.accountgridctr',
    menuDisabled: true,
    hideHeaders: true,
    cls: 'forecasting_grid',
    sortableColumns: false,
    scroll: 'none',
    rowEditor: Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        cls: 'editable_input'
    }),
    columns: [],
    initComponent: function () {
        this.plugins = [this.rowEditor];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: can u provide the fiddle? and where is screenshoot?

Comment: Its difficult for me to do fiddle for this while layout: 'fit', it does not working

Comment: I too faced the same problem,but never got a solution to it.